# Select result Append data from another field if duplicate row is find

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I do select on on column in a table, but I want if there is duplicate row in that column, to append data from another column.

I get this data from a `select` statement:

```
MOD_CDS_TEXT           MOD_PCON_START   MOD_PCON_END
----------------------------------------------------
CORDOBA (6K1, 6K2)        199302          199910
CORDOBA (6K2)             199906          200210
CORDOBA (6L2)             200209          200911
CORDOBA Vario (6K5)       199906          200212
CORDOBA Vario (6K5)       199608          199906
EXEO (3R2)                200812            NULL
```

As you can see in select in `MOD_CDS_TEXT` column, there are two same rows: CORDOBA Vario (6K5)

What I need to do is whenever there is same 2 or 3 or n rows with same data then I want to append data from the other columns and get this result:

```
MOD_CDS_TEXT              MOD_PCON_START    MOD_PCON_END
----------------------------------------------------------
CORDOBA (6K1, 6K2)            199302          199910
CORDOBA (6K2)                 199906          200210
CORDOBA (6L2)                 200209          200911
CORDOBA Vario (6K5)(99_02)    199906          200212
CORDOBA Vario (6K5)(96_99)    199608          199906
EXEO (3R2)                    200812            NULL
```

I've managed to do something, but I get only the second duplicate row as I want, any ideas how to Make also the first row from duplicates as the second:

Here is what I've done:

```
SELECT (IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MOD_CDS_TEXT ORDER BY (SELECT MOD_CDS_TEXT)) = 1,
            MOD_CDS_TEXT,
            MOD_CDS_TEXT + '(' + SUBSTRING(MOD_PCON_START, 3, 2) + '_' + SUBSTRING(MOD_PCON_END, 3, 2) + ')')
       ) AS TEST
FROM TestTable;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? SQL is the wrong tool for the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first row of the duplicates, the ROW_NUMBER is 1, so the original value is used. But you don't want to inspect the ROW_MUMBER but the number of occurances of the value (COUNT), so use the following:

```
SELECT 
  CASE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MOD_CDS_TEXT)
    WHEN 1 THEN MOD_CDS_TEXT
    ELSE MOD_CDS_TEXT + '(' 
         + SUBSTRING(MOD_PCON_START, 3, 2) + '_' 
         + SUBSTRING(MOD_PCON_END, 3, 2) + ')'
  END AS TEST
FROM TestTable;
```